# iPhone iOS crash

Tags: ios

Today my iPhone shut off instantly as I pressed the sleep/wake button to wake its screen; the phone was on. There was no spinning animation as it shut down. I briefly saw the screen flash to the "locked" view before it went black.

When I restarted the phone it indicated that I had 42% battery remaining.

At the time of the "crash", I was near the finish of a 2.5 mile run, and I was running a development build of [iMapMyFitness](http://www.mapmyfitness.com/imapmy/iphone/). It was relatively cold outside -- probably between 30 and 40 degrees F.

I downloaded an app called [System Log](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-log/id428012606?mt=8), and it shows the following two diagnostics with timestamps just before the crash. The next diagnostic is approximately 8 minutes later after I restarted the phone.

```
Message
    Exiting...
Facility
    com.apple.console
ASLMessageID
    655
Level
    5
Sender
    com.apple.assetsd
Time
    1325797737
PID
    78

Message
    MultitouchHID(1cd0e030) uilock state: 0 -> 1
Facility
    kern
ASLMessageID
    656
Level
    5
Sender
    SpringBoard
Time
    1325797751
PID
    30
```

Is this indicative of an iOS defect, an app defect, a hardware problem, or even something else?

Comment: I'm unclear on one point - are you a developer of iMapMyFitness, or an end user?

Comment: The log you pasted is irrelevant.

Comment: I am a developer, and I do work at MapMyFitness. This is absolutely a software development question. The premise of the question is: could my app be causing the OS crash I observed, and if so, how could I isolate the cause so that I can fix it?

Comment: This log doesn't give you any hints on what the problem is, it is just a list of what did send messages to the console. And the messages basically say "shutting down". Is there are crash report available?

Comment: I would love to know how to get a kernel crash report from my iPhone. Is there a way? How?

Comment: @MattMcClure - Connect your device to Xcode, go to the Organizer, and find it in your Devices tab. There should be a listing of crash logs for various applications under Device Logs, and you should be able to see output from any system-level errors in the Console there.

Comment: The most recent crash log in Xcode > Organizer is from 12/31. The crash logs visible there don't seem to include kernel crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a software problem, however, with the log you posted, it's hard to tell exactly what caused it.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a kernel log with more information?

Comment: You might be able to find something with a jailbreak, but other than that, I don't think so.